# What causes composer.lock to add/remove security coverage and change GPL license string on every commit?

Tags: composer

It seems like every time we run `composer require drupal/some_contrib` on a particular project multiple lines in the lock file change in small ways that have no effect but make it hard to see the real dependency update changes if any. These changes are usually reverted on the next commit. These changes are mainly of two kinds:

1. The license text changes from/to "GPL-2.0+"/"GPL-2.0-or-later"
2. The Drupal security coverage status is added or removed.

What causes this?

I verified if it is only one developer machine that makes the changes or makes the changes in a particular "direction". This is not the case. Sometimes the same developer's commit will add the security coverage and sometimes remove it.

Seeing if some developers have a different version of composer. We all have similar versions: 1.6.3 or 1.6.4

Here is a sample from a composer.lock file that had the coverage added during the last composer update command:

```
        {
        "name": "drupal/admin_views",
        "version": "1.6.0",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://git.drupal.org/project/admin_views",
            "reference": "7.x-1.6"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/admin_views-7.x-1.6.zip",
            "reference": "7.x-1.6",
            "shasum": "a56a61d203f9cc79ab17c497c59a56ded1ef1d3c"
        },
        "require": {
            "drupal/drupal": "~7.0",
            "drupal/views": "*",
            "drupal/views_bulk_operations": "^3.2"
        },
        "type": "drupal-module",
        "extra": {
            "branch-alias": {
                "dev-1.x": "1.x-dev"
            },
            "drupal": {
                "version": "7.x-1.6",
                "datestamp": "1470247980",
                "security-coverage": {
                    "status": "covered",
                    "message": "Covered by Drupal's security advisory policy"
                }
            }
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packages.drupal.org/7/downloads",
        "license": [
            "GPL-2.0-or-later"
        ],
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "damiankloip",
                "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/user/1037976"
            },
            {
                "name": "dawehner",
                "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/user/99340"
            },
            {
                "name": "fizk",
                "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/user/473174"
            },
            {
                "name": "sun",
                "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/user/54136"
            }
        ],
        "description": "Replaces all system object management pages in Drupal core with real views.",
        "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views",
        "support": {
            "source": "http://cgit.drupalcode.org/admin_views"
        }
    },
```

Comment: The Drupal security coverage status is not indicated in any Composer file. For what I recall, not even a .info file would report if a project opted into security coverage. That is information the update server on Drupal.org can eventually give out.

Comment: We are getting the coverage status added (every other time). I have added a sample to the question.